# How to serialize entity relation ManyToOne in Symfony Serializer?

Tags: php, symfony

For example I have relation User→Posts and I want to use Symfony Serialize Component to get id on user in Post:

```
/**
 * @var User
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="posts")
 * @Groups({"public"})
 */
private $user;
```

How to get JSON for Post entity with user id?

```
{
   ...
   "user_id": 123,
   ...
}
```

But also be able to serialize User.

Comment: Anton Medvedev Why do you need to use serializer, just for getting json?
You can try entity transformers and they may work great for your needs.

Comment: Because I'm building json api, not forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can use Handling Serialization Depth to avoid `CircularReferenceException` on entity relation.
 (https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-serialization-depth)

```
<?php
namespace Acme;

class MyObj
{
    public $foo;

    /**
     * @var self
     */
    public $child;
}

$level1 = new MyObj();
$level1->foo = 'level1';

$level2 = new MyObj();
$level2->foo = 'level2';
$level1->child = $level2;

$level3 = new MyObj();
$level3->foo = 'level3';
$level2->child = $level3;
```

---

produce:

```
$result = $serializer->normalize($level1, null, array('enable_max_depth' => true));
/*
$result = array(
    'foo' => 'level1',
    'child' => array(
            'foo' => 'level2',
            'child' => array(
                    'child' => null,
                ),
        ),
);
*/
```

Comment: You are missing the important part which is to add the @MaxDepth(1) annotation to the variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

So something like this will work:

```
/**
 * @return int|null
 * @Groups({"public"})
 */
public function getUserId(): ?int
{
    return $this->getUser()->getId();
}
```